# Генерация dto при помощи OpenAPI Specification (Swagger)

Tags: java, spring, rest, swagger

Всем привет! Возможно ли используя json cхему генерировать Dto на Java при помощи Swagger?
Если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, буду рад рассмотреть другие варианты конвертации
json -> Dto

Comment: да возможно
есть плагины
есть генератор в онлайн редакторе https://editor.swagger.io/

Answer (score 1):

Да, это возможно.
Помимо онлайн-генераторов можно воспользоваться [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator).
Имеется как [Maven-плагин](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin), так и просто [Jar-файл](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/6.1.0/openapi-generator-cli-6.1.0.jar) для использования с CLI.

Ниже тривиальный пример генерации клиента используя CLI:

```
java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate \
  -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json \
  --api-package com.petstore.client.api \
  --model-package com.petstore.client.model \
  --invoker-package com.petstore.client.invoker \
  --group-id com.petstore\
  --artifact-id spring-openapi-generator-api-client \
  --artifact-version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT \
  -g java \
  -p java8=true \
  --library resttemplate \
  -o spring-openapi-generator-api-client
```

Чтобы просмотреть все параметры, связанные с Java-генератором, введите команду:

```
java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar config-help -g java
```

---

#### Ссылки по теме

- [Документация к Maven-плагину](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin)
- [Документация по настройке Java-генератора](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/java.md)
- [Статья по настройке и использованию Maven-плагина для генерации серверной части](https://www.baeldung.com/java-openapi-generator-server)
- [Статья по настройке генератора клиента](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-rest-client-swagger-codegen)
- [Спецификация Open API v.3.0.2](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.2.md)